# Create variable from last part of string after the last "/" character

Tags: string, bash

I have strings that I want to extract to a variable the part after the last / character.

Sample strings are:

```
apps/test/wordpress/wordpressA
apps/wordpress/wordpressA
apps/wordpressA
wordpressA
```

I want to create a `new_variable` with just `wordpressA` in it from all the samples.  I won't know how many `/` characters there may be in each variable.

Comment: This is very similar to [Expression after last specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9532654/3266847)

Comment: Or [Get the characters after the last index of a substring from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15548277/3266847)

Comment: Note that I strongly recommend using [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15548660/14122) rather than the accepted one.

Comment: ...btw, this is also covered as part of [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string).

Comment: This particular case is completely covered with `basename` so one does not need to use any regexps thus making everything simpler to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Easy

Each **echo** below will output **wordpressA**

```
strInput='apps/test/wordpress/wordpressA'   
echo "${strInput##*/}"   
   
strInput='apps/wordpress/wordpressA'   
echo "${strInput##*/}"   
   
strInput='apps/wordpressA'   
echo "${strInput##*/}"   
   
strInput='wordpressA'   
echo "${strInput##*/}"
```